# How to put VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF in Zebra code

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

This is my code for the ZPL label:

```
^XA^FS^FT215,210^A0N,28,28^FH^FD300 mg (1 ½ tablet)^XZ
```

but it shows like this:

[image]

I want it to be shown as ½, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to UTF-8 encoding using `^CI28`:

```
^XA^CI28^FT215,210^A0N,28,28^FD300 mg (1 ½ tablet)^FS^XZ
```

Comment: thank you , u made my day , i thought i need to install a driver to allow special characters ..

Answer (score 0):

This label is shown correct in the Labelary Online ZPL Viewer, but the printer Zebra ZD410 doesn't print the ½ symbol...is it a problem of compatibility?

^XA
^MMT
^PW400
^LL200
^LS-40
^CI28
^FO60,20^ADN,15,10^FD35663_AVE^FS
^FO210,20^A0N,25,25^FD37 ½^FS
^FO60,45^BY2^BEN,60,N,N^FD8445087656818^FS
^FO170,130^ADN,30,15^FD199^FS
^FO250,130^ADN,20,10^FDEUR^FS
^XZ

Comment: Soluction: ^CI27 instead of ^CI28